# How to make class relative to QWidget tabs in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a Main Window with a Tab Widget. For example purpose, the tab widget has 2 tabs/pages. I want to create a class per tab so that I can manage objects (buttons, line edits, etc) found in the respective tab inside that class.

Here is an image of 1 Main Window that contains 1 Tab Widget with 2 Tabs.
[image]

Here is my working code but does not work since I am still looking how to realize this concept.

```
class Tab1Process(Ui_MainWindow):   # Class that can call objects relative to Tab 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.tab1_browse_button.clicked.connect(self.do_something)

    def do_something(self):
        print("Did something.")

class Tab2Process(Ui_MainWindow):   # Class that can call objects relative to Tab 2
    def __init__(self):
        self.tab2_browse_button.clicked.connect(self.do_something_else)

    def do_something_else(self):
        print("Did something else.")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tab1_process = Tab1Process() # This does not work, but I think I need this 'concept' to register the above classes
        self.tab1_process.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Here is a repo of that example: https://gitlab.com/cnpante/pyqt5-gui

`python gui.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand where you got the concept that widgets can be magically separated. In your case to implement the objective in the background is each page is a QWidget that has its own .ui, and then promote those personalized pages in the main .ui.

tab1.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="tab1_browse_button">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>300</x>
     <y>122</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Browse</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="tab1_text">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>120</y>
     <width>256</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

tab2.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="tab2_browse_button">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>310</x>
     <y>132</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Browse</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="tab2_text">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>256</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

main.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>571</width>
    <height>429</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab1">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 1</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="Tab1" name="widget" native="true"/>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab2">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 2</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <widget class="Tab2" name="widget_2" native="true"/>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>571</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>Tab1</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>tab1</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
  <customwidget>
   <class>Tab2</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>tab2</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

```
pyuic5 tab1.ui -o tab1_ui.py -x
pyuic5 tab2.ui -o tab2_ui.py -x
pyuic5 main.ui -o main_ui.py -x
```

tab1.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from tab1_ui import Ui_Form


class Tab1(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tab1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tab1_browse_button.clicked.connect(self.do_something)

    def do_something(self):
        print("Did something.")
```

tab2.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from tab2_ui import Ui_Form


class Tab2(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tab2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tab2_browse_button.clicked.connect(self.do_something_else)

    def do_something_else(self):
        print("Did something else.")
```

main.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
├── main.py
├── main.ui
├── main_ui.py
├── tab1.py
├── tab1.ui
├── tab1_ui.py
├── tab2.py
├── tab2.ui
└── tab2_ui.py
```

Comment: Let me try this. I just had the concept in mind. I was thinking of Django-y configurations.

Comment: @Nikko Qt is not a framework unlike django, in conclusion Qt does not use the django paradigm or any backend

Comment: What is the object inside the tab that holds the widget? Is that a groupbox?

Comment: Or was it the Widget Container?

Comment: @Nikko Please open the .ui with Qt Designer and you will see how they are created

Comment: I do not get promotion. What needs to be the class name? Should it be the same with file name of tab1.py?

Comment: @Nikko See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Comment: I still dont get it. I created actions.py that contains the class. In my main I promoted using the class name and header using actions. In my main, I see `from actions import Tab1`. But errors comes: `No module named actions`

Comment: Okay I get it now. Something to do with my directories. Thanks!